# How can I run private instances of my Discord Bot for each server?

Tags: discord, discord.js, virtualization, multiple-instances

A bot I'm working on offers a premium subscription and as one of the perks, I'd like to offer users a chance to change stuff like the avatar, username, status, etc. for the bot in their server, similar to how [Mee6](https://mee6.xyz) does it. What would be the simplest way to go about this?
I'm thinking Docker and Containers would work out well, but I feel as if there's an easier way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but user need to provide their bot's token, you don't need to use docker container, you only need to create multiple `Client`

```js
// Client one
const client1 = new Discord.Client({...});
// Client two
const client2 = new Discord.Client({...});

// login to client
client1.login("client 1 token")
client2.login("client 2 token")
```

If you want to manage more client, you can create a collection then put all client into it.

Comment: This would be one of the many ways I would've imagined it but it seems a bit inefficient. Maybe I can do that dynamically or something of the sorts?

Comment: You can, like create a array or Collection and put all clients into it.